# Chrome-headless doesn't like the kerberos ticket

Tags: kerberos, google-chrome-headless

The website I am trying to test headless-ly with chrome requires a Single Sign On. So I generated a key tab for a user that has access to the website and did a kinit for that user. But for some reason headless-chrome doesn't see the kerberos ticket and doesn't load the webpage.

And yes I have whitelisted the website from our domain using `auth-server-whitelist` and `auth-negotiate-delegate-whitelist` and I am using chrome driver version `2.45.615355`

Just wanted to check if any one here was successful using the kerberos for testing in headless-chrome.

Comment: Does a normal version of Chrome work?

Comment: Yes the exact same test case works in normal chrome

Comment: Where are you changing these settings ? negotiate-delegate-whitelist, auth-server-whitelist